# Reporting missing values per subgroup in R from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data, na, sapply

I have a data frame resembling the one below.

```
Group Expenditure Date
A     56434       22 June 2014
B     54231       1 July 2013
B     1412        9 May 2011
A     NA           28 July 2009
A     NA           3 July 2009
C     98          2 July 1999
C     NA           14 July 2004
```

I'm interested in creating missing values reports for the Expenditure column. One value should return the number of missing values per column, this is solved with use of the following code

```
sapply(exp.dta, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
```

In addition, I would like to report the number of missing values for each date. The date column is formatted as a proper date with use of the **as.Date** function. As for now, I'm not interested in reporting missing values per subgroup.

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks for showing the interest. The data is imported from the CSV file where missing expenditure data is coded as NA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the code you already have written, you could add `split` to it,

```
dat <- read.table(h=T, text = "Group Expenditure Date
  A     56434       22-June-2014
  B     54231       1-July-2013
  B     1412        9-May-2011
  A     NA           28-July-2009
  A     NA           3-July-2009
  C     98          2-July-1999
  C     NA           14-July-2004")

> sapply(split(dat$Expenditure, dat$Group), function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
# A B C 
# 2 0 1
```

or for each date,

```
> s <- split(dat$Expenditure, dat$Date)
> as.matrix(sapply(s, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))
#              [,1]
# 14-July-2004    1
# 1-July-2013     0
# 22-June-2014    0
# 28-July-2009    1
# 2-July-1999     0
# 3-July-2009     1
# 9-May-2011      0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 library(plyr)
 ddply(your.data, .(Date), summarize, nNA = sum(is.na(Expenditure))
```

This splits up the data into subgroups by `Date` and applies the function `sum(is.na())` to the `Expenditure` column for these subgroups.

For instance,

```
 df <- read.table(text="Group Expenditure Date
 A     56434       22June2014
 B     54231       1July2013
 B     1412        9May2011
 A     NA           28July2009
 A     NA           3July2009
 C     98          2July1999
 C     NA           14July2004 ", sep="", header=T)

 ddply(df, .(Date), summarize, nNA=sum(is.na(Expenditure)))
```

yields:

```
         Date nNA
 1 14July2004   1
 2  1July2013   0
 3 22June2014   0
 4 28July2009   1
 5  2July1999   0
 6  3July2009   1
 7   9May2011   0
```

There are also several `base`-solutions. Here some examples:

- Using `by`

  ```
  by(df, df$Date, function(x) sum(is.na(x$Expenditure)))
  ```
- Using `tapply`

  ```
  with(df, tapply(Expenditure, Date, function(x) sum(is.na(x))))
  ```
- Using `aggregate` (hat tip to @user20650)

  ```
  aggregate(df$Expenditure, by=list(df$Date), FUN= function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
  ```

which all give the same result but with slightly different formats. Pick which one you like the most. For a more general treatment, this kind of problem is called "split-apply-combine", see e.g. [here](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper).

Comment: Your link on 'split-apply-combine' strategy ("The Split-Apply-Combine Strategy for Data Analysis" by Hadley Wickham) is really useful. For network stumblers, this with `data.table`might be also helpful: http://www.brodieg.com/?p=7

Answer (score 1):

Or, using `dplyr`:

```
library('dplyr')
summarize(group_by(df, Date), nNA = sum(is.na(Expenditure)))
```